# Android AudioTrack write blocks for the whole period of playback

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I am using `AudioTrack` class to play a stream of raw sound data:

```
AudioTrack audioTrack;
int sampleRate = 11025;
int channelConfigIn = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
int channelConfigOut = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
.....
int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,channelConfigOut,audioFormat);
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,sampleRate,channelConfigOut,audioFormat,bufferSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    audioTrack.play();
```

Then on a separate thread:

```
while(true)
{
    short [] buffer = new short[14500];
    //fill buffer with sound data
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    audioTrack.write(buffer,0,14500);
    Log.i("time",(System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "");
}
```

My problem is that the log always shows that the `write` method blocks for about 0.6 second, that is the same as the played sound length (14500 samples), moreover the phone is not responding during the playback, the main tread almost can not do anything anyone can help...

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/tz2Mvh5G) just works ok

Answer (score 0):

You are using the blocking version of the `write()` method. You can use [write(float[],int,int,int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#write(float[],%20int,%20int,%20int)) instead, passing WRITE_NON_BLOCKING as the 4th parameter, but that would only write as much data as can fit in the play buffer. I generally prefer the approach you already have (dedicating a thread to writing). You should expect each call to block; after all, the play buffer can only fit so much data, and to make more space, sound must be played (which takes time). 14500 samples is ~1.3 seconds of sound at your chosen sample rate, so I'm guessing it takes you about .7 seconds to fill `buffer` each time.

I cannot tell, based on the code presented, why your UI thread is not responding.

Comment: Thank you for response, first the method you suggested needs apk 23, so I did not use it although I know it exists, second I did use `HandlerThread` to solve it, it seems the priority of the thread was the cause of it. Anyway it seems there is an accumulated latency that causes the playback to be late a little as time go on